# Run .net event Asynchronously?

Tags: c#, .net, events, .net-4.0

I met this interesting question :

If I have an event and 2 long calculated function subscribed to this event :

It seems its work synchronously :  ( *method 2 will have to wait to method 1 to finish*)

```
public class A
{
    public event Action f;
    public void Start()
    {
        f();
    }
}
void Main()
{
    A a = new A();
    a.f += Work1;
    a.f += Work2;
    a.Start();
}
public void Work1()
{
    "w1 started".Dump();
    decimal k = 0;
    for(decimal i = 0; i < (99999999); i++)
    {
        k++;
    }
    "w1 ended".Dump();
}
public void Work2()
{
    "w2 started".Dump();
    decimal k = 0;
    for(decimal i = 0; i < 99999999; i++)
    {
        k++;
    }
    "w2 ended".Dump();
}
```

*Result :*

[image]

Question :

IMHO , it has an invocation list and *THAT'S* is the reason why it run synchronously.

How can I make it run `A-synchronously` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The event itself will always run it subscribers one after another.

But you can always e.g. wrap your method with a [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx)

```
void Main()
{
    A a = new A();
    a.f += () => Task.Factory.StartNew(Work1);
    a.f += () => Task.Factory.StartNew(Work2);
    a.Start();
}
```

or use some other kind of multithreading.

Comment: @Tigran Yes, but you could also use `BackgroundWorker`, `Thread` or asynchronous delegate invocation with `BeginInvoke` etc.